# How do I print both an expression and its value in Rust?

Tags: debugging, logging, reflection, macros, rust

Is there a way of doing this?

```
self.mega_ultra_field = 100500;
print_expr_and_value!(self.mega_ultra_field);
```

Output:

```
self.mega_ultra_field 100500
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Premade solution

Use [`dbg!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.dbg.html):

```rust
dbg!(self.mega_ultra_field);
```

```
[src/main.rs:16] self.mega_ultra_field = 100500
```

## Writing your own

Use [`stringify!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.stringify.html):

```rust
macro_rules! print_expr_and_value {
    ($e:expr) => {
        eprintln!("{} {}", stringify!($e), $e)
    };
}
```

```rust
struct Foo {
    mega_ultra_field: i32,
}

impl Foo {
    fn bar(&mut self) {
        self.mega_ultra_field = 100500;
        print_expr_and_value!(self.mega_ultra_field);

        dbg!(self.mega_ultra_field);
    }
}

fn main() {
    Foo {
        mega_ultra_field: 0,
    }
    .bar();
}
```

```
self.mega_ultra_field 100500
```